# Get text in <a> tag on image button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-listview

```
<td style="float:right;padding-top:5px">
   <a class="testAccId">#:AccountID#</a>                                                                   
   <img id="imgbtn" class="clsimg" onclick="history(event)" src="../Content/images/history.png" />                                 
</td>
```

I have an anchor tag and an image button, on clicking the image button I need the text in that anchor tag, and that 'td' is in loop, so if I have 2 items, when clicking one the img in 1st tile, I should get the text in  from 1 st tile.

I have tried the following options.

```
 function history(e) {
        var a = $(this).closest('td').next().find('.testAccId').text();
        alert(a);
    }


 function history(e) {

    var a= ($(".imgbtn").closest(".testAccId")).text();
    alert(a);
}

function history(e) {
        var a = $(e.currentTarget).closest('td').next().find('.testAccId').text();
        alert(a);
    }
```

In the alert I am getting empty or, object object.

Please help me with this.

Comment: try this,
  `function history(e) {
        var a = $(this).prev().text();
        alert(a);
    }`  

or 

`function history(e) {
        var a = $(this).prevAll('. testAccId').text();
        alert(a);
    }`

Comment: I am getting an empty alert box using this.

Comment: try this, `function history(e) { var a = $(e.target).prev().text(); alert(a); }` or `function history(e) { var a = $(e.target).prevAll('. testAccId').text(); alert(a); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like, it's a bit hard to tell w/o an example but this should work as long as the structure is consistent

```
function history(e) {
 var a = ($(e.target).prev().html());
  alert(a)
}
```

I updated the code here as well, should be functional now ^^

Comment: I am getting 'Undefined' in the alert box.

Comment: oh yeah you're right, I fixed it and threw together this code pen for you, let me know if this helps! http://codepen.io/csavage1994/pen/EWWJZe

Comment: Hmm, would you mind posting a more complete example of the html? Maybe provide a code pen that I could play around with?

Answer (score 1):

Another Option:
PS: make sure to include Jquery in head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".clsimg").click(function(){
            alert($(this).parent('td').find('a').text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can match with the closest element

```
 function history(e) {

var a= ($(".imgbtn").closest($('.testAccId')).text();
    alert(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By removing inline JS and using a nicer click event and a combination of `.closest()` and `.find()`

```js
$(".clsimg").on("click", function() {
  var aText = $(this).closest("td").find("a").text();
  alert(aText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="testAccId">#:AccountID#</a>
      <img id="imgbtn" class="clsimg" src="//placehold.it/50x50" alt="Desc">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but for some reason if I use ".On" function the control is not even going into that, so I have given the function in theOnclick event and working on it.

Answer (score 0):

A and IMG are children of the same *parent*, they are *siblings*, so all you need is this:

```
$('.clsimg').click(function() {
    alert($(this).siblings('a').text());
});
```

[JSFiddle working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DanieleAlessandra/wror285x/)

Comment: I am getting an empty alert box with this.

Comment: Maybe there is something else on your page, i tested my solution on jsfiddle and it seems to work, look --> https://jsfiddle.net/DanieleAlessandra/wror285x/